# Do singular distributions have any real-world applications?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity, applications, absolute-continuity

Do [singular probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_distribution) have any real-world applications, or are they just a pure-mathematical curiosity? I can't imagine a real quantity that they would describe. But on the other hand, [singular functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_function) do have surprising applications, e.g. regarding the fractional quantum Hall effect in condensed-matter physics, so maybe singular probability distributions do as well.

By "real-world application" I don't mean a real phenomenon which could in principle be modeled by a singular distribution, but rather a situation in which engineers, scientists, financial analysts, or other non-mathematicians actually *do* use them in the context of a commercial application or other non-mathematical "product".

Answer (score 1):

For example, consider an infinite sequence of fair coin-flips, corresponding to iid Bernoulli-$1/2$ random variables $X_n$.  Then $2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty 3^{-n} X_n$ has a singular distribution whose cdf is the "devil's staircase".

EDIT: If you want to make it seem more "real-world", you might rephrase this in terms of return on investments or something similar.  The point is that a rapidly converging sum of discrete random variables is quite likely to have a singular distribution.

Comment: That's interesting, although I wouldn't call it a "real-world application".

Comment: @tparker, that is a very weird comment. A sequence of Bernoulli variables models any sequence of binary experiments: one talks about a coin simply it is convenient to think of the abstract situation.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I've edited my question to clarify the scope of what I consider a "real-world application". I'd welcome any examples, but I'm skeptical that non-mathematicians actually use these singular distributions in practice rather than just using absolutely continuous probability distributions.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez An $N \to \infty$ limit is almost always artificial in the real world, but applied types are happy to use that idealization if the result is easier to work with than the finite case. It often is, but in this case the limiting case is arguably more complicated than the finite one, so I'm not sure whether it's useful in (non-mathematical) practice.

Comment: That limit is used in pretty much all applications. You are not quite sure «whether it is useful in practice»: that makes one guess that you have not seen any practice at all, really.

Comment: On the other hand, the reason we usually consider the limit is precisely that for many (most?) situations it is *easier* to deal with that the finite case. This is appreciated very immediately when one tries to do things

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Please do not invent quotations that I never said and then use them for ad hominem attacks. I certainly never questioned whether the $N \to \infty$ limit is ever useful in practice. You are precisely agreeing with what I said: the $N \to \infty$ limit is useful *when it is simpler then the finite expression*, which is often, but not always, the case. (Also, please use the @ symbol so that I can see your responses.)

Comment: @tparker, Attack?  What quotation? Ad hominem? What on earth are you taking about?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Ah, I think I see the miscommunication. You mis-parsed my comment five comments up. I certainly was not saying that the *general* $N \to \infty$ limit is not useful in practice. I was saying that the (rare special case of the $N \to \infty$ limit in which the limiting expression is more complicated than the finite expression) is not useful in practice. The "in this case" was supposed to include the entire rest of the sentence, not just until the comma. I was very confused about why you just repeated my exact point, but I see you did not realize that that *was* my point.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one application that might interest you. Consider an integrable function f on $\mathbb R$ such that $2f(x)=3f(3x)+3f(3x-1)$ a.e.. It turns out that $f=0$ a.e.. There seems to be no simple way of doing this even if you assume that f is smooth function. There is an elegant proof by relating it to cantor set and a singular distribution function. This is Problem 261 in 'Exercises in Analysis 201-300' at statmathbc.wordpress.com where complete solutions are provided on request.

Answer (score 1):

Frequent examples involve probability measures over $\mathbb R^{n\ge2}$ with mass concentrated on a manifold $M$ of dimension less than $n$, such as any distribution over the unit sphere (a hypersurface of dimension $n-1$).

In such situations one can sometimes define a "(hyper)surface density" $\sigma$ which can be integrated over a measurable subset $A \subset M$ as $\mathbb P(A) = \int_A\sigma \ d\mu$, where $\mu$ measures the $(n - 1)$-dimensional volume on the manifold $M$.